If Goodridge v. Dept. of Public Health is overruled, what will be the status of people in same-sex marriages?
Let's say Goodridge v. Dept. of Public Health is overruled by the Supreme Court, like Roe and Casey, and same-sex marriages become banned in some states. What will be the legal status of the previously married people - divorced? Annulled? If they had common property or kids, what will happen to those?
Also, is it possible that Lawrence v. Texas is overruled and sodomy becomes criminalized in some states, while in other states same-sex unions are still legal, or there is some kind of protection against state laws clashing like that?

You mean the gay marriage that was made a right by Obergefell?

This is too speculative IMHO to answer. It would depend upon the details of the legal reasoning in the opinion and a host of other details, and there are really no close precedents to provide guidance where a large group of people lost the right to be legally married. Many states had already legalized gay marriage in 2015 when it became mandated as a matter of federal constitutional law.

Goodridge v. Dept. of Public Health, 798 N.E.2d 941 (2003), is a landmark Massachusetts Supreme Judicial Court case in which the Court held that the Massachusetts Constitution requires the state to legally recognize same-sex marriage. Obergefell v. Hodges, 576 U.S. 644 (2015) reached the same conclusion as a matter of U.S. Constitutional law.

The question also asks too many things. Overruling Lawrence and Obergefell respectively would present distinct issues and fitting both in one question is too much.
